# Grep find text in a file and print the text 3 lines before it

Tags: text-processing

I have a file and will be looking for multiple file names in the file.  Example search text `intl_reg.jcl`.  Once I find it I need to get the text that is 3 lines above it.  For example below is 4 lines from the file.  The text before the description "registered international students with balances" will always be CHOICE followed by the description.

```
CHOICE List registered international students with balances   
SHORTCUT 8  
PROCESS CHDIR /d3/locban/arsys  
PROCESS CMD ksh /d3/locban/arsys/intl_reg.jcl
```

I need the grep command to list it like the below:

```
intl_reg.jcl  registered international students with balances
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What did it do? What did you expect it to do?

Comment: Where did the word `List` go from your example output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following `awk` programs would work.

**Option 1: Double-Pass**

```
awk -v d=3 -v s="intl_reg.jcl" '(NR==FNR) && index($0,s){i=FNR;nextfile} 
                                FNR==(i-d){printf "%s\t%s\n",s,$0; exit}' input.txt input.txt
```

Here, the input file is specified twice so that it is processed twice. The string to search for is passed as `awk` variable `s`, the distance as `awk` variable `d`.

- In the first pass, where `NR`, the global line counter, is equal to `FNR`, the per-file line counter, each line is checked for the occurence of the string. If found, the line number is stored in a variable `i`, and execution immediately skips to the next file (= the next iteration over the same file).
- In the second pass, the program checks if the current line number is `d` less than the previously identified occurence of the pattern, as stored in `i`. When that line is encountered, it is printed together with the search string, and the program terminates (so as not to idly loop over the rest of the file.

**Option 2: Single-Pass**

In order to speed up the process, and for cases where re-visiting a file is not possible (e.g. because it is a pipe), a single-pass solution with buffering is also possible. In this case, a FIFO buffer of length `d` is needed, which means that is is unpractical if `d` gets too large (but it should rarely be a problem):

```
awk -v d=3 -v s="intl_reg.jcl" 'FNR>1{for (j=d;j>0;j--) {buf[j]=buf[j-1]}; buf[0]=$0}
                            FNR>d && match($0,s) {printf "%s\t%s\n",s,buf[d];exit}' input.txt
```

This will successively fill a buffer `buf` with the last `d+1` lines, where the buffer content is shifted "one up" at every new line and the current line is always in `buf[0]`. Once the search string is found, it will print the content of `buf[d]`, which is `d` lines before the current line. Again, the program then terminates immediately for performance reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
~$ raku -e 'my @a; for lines() { 
            if @a.elems == 4 { @a.push($_); @a.shift } 
            elsif @a.elems < 4 { @a.push($_) }; 
            if .match( /intl_reg\.jcl/ ) and @a.elems == 4 {
            say $<>.Str, @a[0].split( /<?after List>/ ).[1] }; 
            };' file
```

Briefly, an array `@a` is declared and `lines` are read-in off the command line. Input is `push`ed onto the `@a` array until `elems` equals 4, then the first element is `shift`ed off to maintain a max size of 4 elements.

If a `match` is seen `and` the array contains 4 element then the `$<>` match-variable is printed (`$<>` is the same as `$/`), followed by the line recorded 3 lines earlier, appropriately `split` to return the desired string.

Sample Input:

```
A CHOICE List registered international students with balances   
A SHORTCUT 8  
A PROCESS CHDIR /d3/locban/arsys  
A PROCESS CMD ksh /d3/locban/arsys/intl_reg.jcl
B CHOICE List registered international students with balances   
B SHORTCUT 8  
B PROCESS CHDIR /d3/locban/arsys  
B PROCESS CMD ksh /d3/locban/arsys/intl_reg.jcl
```

Sample Output:

```
intl_reg.jcl registered international students with balances   
intl_reg.jcl registered international students with balances
```

https://raku.org

Answer (score 0):

```
match=intl_reg.jcl
tac {file} |
    sed -n "/$match/ { n; n; n; s/^CHOICE/$match/p }"
```

Ensure that `$match` contains neither `/` nor a Regular Expression operator. (Note that `.` is actually a wildcard character so breaks this rule immediately. This may or may not be an issue for you.)

Comment: After I run this the first time I get the correct results.  When I change the match= file name to something else and the file name to a different file name I always just get the first result.  What am I missing?

Comment: When I run match=intl_reg.lst tac studf.amnu | sed -n "/$match/ { n; n; n; s/^CHOICE/$match/p }"

Comment: Either there's only one match or you're going to need to update your question with a better example

Comment: When I run match=intl_reg.lst tac studf.amnu | sed -n "/$match/ { n; n; n; s/^CHOICE/$match/p }"  I get the correct results.  However, when I change it match=joesally tac studf.amnu | sed -n "/$match/ { n; n; n; s/^CHOICE/$match/p }"
 I get the same result as I did for the first one.  the match of joesally doesn't exist in the file studf.amnu.  What am I missing?

Comment: It's really difficult to see what you're doing, @Jonathan, because you don't quote your code in the comments and (more importantly) you're not updating your question where you can easily format the text. However, it looks like you might be trying to set the `match=value` in the same command as the `tac`, and that won't work (i.e. `match=joesally tac studft.amnu` is wrong and doesn't do what you seem to think it should). Look again at my code: the `match=value` is a separate command on a separate line

Answer (score 0):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk -v t='intl_reg.jcl' '{a[NR%4]=$0} index($0,t){$0=a[(NR-3)%4]; $1=$2=""; print t $0}' file
intl_reg.jcl  registered international students with balances
```